# Separate shapes using horography

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Using the distribution of the intensity values, I need to separate two shapes in an image below :-

[image]

Basically I want to separate two "mountains" by using their slope. Do you have any suggestion on how to design an algorithm for that?

The original image is the following:

[image: original]

Comment: To separate two mountains, while also not separating one mountain due to it's own crevices seems like more of a problem than you might expect. ref: http://xkcd.com/1425/

Comment: You could start by applying this kernel to each set of adjacent pixels in the image `kernel = [0 -1/4 0;-1/4 1 -1/4;0 -1/4 0]` the value of this will help find local maxima.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The boundary will be determined by the **local minimum** of height. Find them is not as easy as it would seem at the first look. I would try this:

1. **create clear ROI mask image**

   let define the **ROI** image colors with meanings:

   ```
   0  - empty space
   1  - slope from left
   2  - slope from right
   3  - hill border
   10 - mountain 1
   11 - mountain 2
   12 - mountain 3 ...
   ```

   and clear the **ROI** with `0`
2. **scan source image in `x` direction**

   and set all downhill slopes from `x+` direction:

   ```
   for (y=0;y<ys;y++)
    for (x=1;x<=xs;x++)
     if ((ROI[y][x]==0)&&(height[y][x-1]>height[y][x]+treshold))
      ROI[y][x]=1;
   ```

   similarly scan the `x-` direction

   ```
   for (y=0;y<ys;y++)
    for (x=xs-2;x>=0;x--)
     if ((ROI[y][x]==0)&&(height[y][x+1]>height[y][x]+treshold))
      ROI[y][x]=2;
   ```

   now you need to find zones in **ROI** between `1,2` and set them as `3` which would be possible border. After this clear all `1,2` **ROI** pixels with `0`. The `treshold` is just sensitivity to hill slopes. This algorithm works best on smooth images so if too many artifacts are present you can try smoothing the source image few times before applying this.
3. **filter out too small borders**

   You should filter out too small **ROI** regions set to `3` to avoid too small hills messing up the whole thing It can be avoided up to a point with the `treshold` value or by merging small regions inside big ones later.
4. **Do #2,#3 for `y`direction (and maybe also diagonals)**
5. **Enlarge the ROI borders with morfologic operations**
6. **fill empty space in ROI with floodfill**

   find first **ROI** pixel set to zero and fill it with `100` , next with `101` etc. During the floodfill you can compute `min,max,avg` height of filled region to discard too flat regions later (as they are not considered hills/mountains).

Answer (score 2):

I would do it using image processing toolbox. Starting from your image, `img`:

```
figure; imshow(img);
```

[image]

First and the trickiest step is to *define* the mountains. One could be satisfied with introducing a hight limit. But depending on your data and your expectation, you could also apply limits to the area. Here I am first considering the hight:

```
bw = im2bw(img, .85);
figure; imshow(bw)
```

[image]

Now I filter out very small areas. You could play with this threshold as well.

```
bw_cleaned = bwareaopen(bw, 100, 4);
figure; imshow(bw_cleaned)
```

[image]

The next steps are to expand the white area in a way that the regions illustrating a peak merge together, then making the convex hull around each peak and finally finding its position:

```
final_bw = bwconvhull(imdilate(bw_cleaned, strel('disk', 50)), 'objects');
figure; imshow(final_bw)
s = regionprops(final_bw, 'Centroid');
centroids = cat(1, s.Centroid);
hold on
plot(centroids(:,1), centroids(:,2), 'b*')
```

[image]

Using `regionprops` you can do more than finding the centroid. [Take a look.](http://de.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html)